# rvest with information spread over multiple views

Tags: r, rvest, rselenium

I want to scrape the ranking on the left of [this page](http://www.kicker.de/news/fussball/bundesliga/spieltag/1-bundesliga/elfmeter-schuetzen-geschichte.html), which is spread over 34 views and which I believe (total newbie to scraping) to be Java-genereated. All views have the same url, so I cannot loop over these.

As far as I gather, each view seems to have node `#elferspielerhistorie_subcont_j td`, starting with `j=0`.

I can scrape the first entries with

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

elfer_url <- "http://www.kicker.de/news/fussball/bundesliga/spieltag/1-bundesliga/elfmeter-schuetzen-geschichte.html"

# first page
elfmeter <- read_html(elfer_url)
Schuetzen <- elfmeter %>% html_nodes("#elferspielerhistorie_subcont_0 td") %>% html_text()
```

My "strategy" is then to click, with RSelenium, on the link for the next page, `paste` the next node and do over. The loop however returns empty entries for the next 33 views (entire code for completeness):

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium)

elfer_url <- "http://www.kicker.de/news/fussball/bundesliga/spieltag/1-bundesliga/elfmeter-schuetzen-geschichte.html"

rD <- rsDriver(port = 4444L, browser = "firefox")
remDr <- rD$client
remDr$navigate(elfer_url)

# first page
elfmeter <- read_html(elfer_url)
Schuetzen <- elfmeter %>% html_nodes("#elferspielerhistorie_subcont_0 td") %>% html_text() %>% matrix(ncol=10, byrow=T) %>% data.frame()

clicknext <- remDr$findElements("xpath","//*[@id='ctl00_PlaceHolderContent_elfer_blaettern_elferhistorie_PagerForward']")

j <- 1
while (j<=34){
  clicknext[[1]]$clickElement()     # sends me to the right view
  #elfmeter <- read_html(elfer_url) # switching this on or off does not change things
  current.node <- paste0("#elferspielerhistorie_subcont_",j," td") # should be the node
  weitere_Schuetzen <- elfmeter %>% html_node(current.node) %>% html_text() %>% matrix(ncol=10, byrow=T) %>% data.frame() # returns empty result
  Schuetzen <- rbind(Schuetzen,weitere_Schuetzen)

  j <- j+1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the views are generated dynamically you have to get the page source on every turn. It might be, that the ID of the next button changes so it is save to also find that button on every iteration.

The following code should work. Notice that I also read out those empty rows which are dropped when the loop has finished:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium)

elfer_url <- "http://www.kicker.de/news/fussball/bundesliga/spieltag/1-bundesliga/elfmeter-schuetzen-geschichte.html"

rD <- rsDriver(port = 4447L, browser = "firefox")
remDr <- rD$client
remDr$navigate(elfer_url)

getTable <- function(x) {
  remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
    read_html %>% 
    html_nodes(paste0("#elferspielerhistorie_subcont_", x, " table")) %>% 
    html_table(fill = T)  %>% 
    .[[1]] %>% 
    data.frame
}

# first page
data <- getTable(0)

for(j in 1:33) {
  next_button <- remDr$findElements("css","a[id=\"ctl00_PlaceHolderContent_elfer_blaettern_elferhistorie_PagerForward\"]") %>% .[[1]]
  remDr$executeScript(script = "arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", args = list(next_button))
  next_button$clickElement()
  # sometimes the loop is too fast and it cannot fetch the table. so pause here
  Sys.sleep(1)
  data <- rbind(data, getTable(j))

  j <- j+1

}
rD$server$stop()

data <- data[-which(data$Spieler == ""),]
dim(data)

> [1] 935  10
```